# Why dose it turn out to be the number 120 but not the character 'x' I want?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSNumber *str = [NSNumber numberWithChar:'x'];

        NSLog(@"%@",str);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the number 120, instead of the character 'x'. Why does it do this?

Comment: Uhm, `NSNumber` is a wrapper for scalar numbers... why did you expect a different result?

Comment: Thank you ,Brad Larson for modifying my question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this: ASCII code of `x` is 120 in decimal. The `'x'` syntax is a convenient syntax for entering small integer constants using their representation as ASCII characters; other than the syntax, constants in single quotes are regular integers.

If you would like the number re-interpreted as a character, use the corresponding format specifier in the `NSLog` call, and get the `char` value from the `NSNumber` object:

```
NSNumber *str = [NSNumber numberWithChar:'x'];
NSLog(@"%c", [str charValue]);
```

Comment: thank you very much, dasblinkenlight. That's what exactly what I need.

Comment: @zhengger You are welcome! If this answers your question, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the outline of a checkmark next to it. This will let others know that you are not actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It has been checked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

From [NSNumber docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar (numeric) type.

in this case it's holding `x`'s ASCII code - how could you expect a number-ish structure to hold a letter? ;))

If you want to use a char, stick with `char`. If you need a whole string, go with `NSString`.